# Is it posible to copy a folder from another computer using a java application locally?

Tags: java, cmd

Before I have copied files from my computer to another and that's not a problem.
But when I try to do the opposite, I can't. I'm trying to copy files from another computer, but I'm running the program in mine.
I'm using java, Windows XP, and I do have the  privileges to use that folder.

This is my code:

```
String rutaO = "pc1234/folder/"; //The folder that i want to copy
String rutaD = "D:/reportes"; // Where I want to put the other folder
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c copy \"" + rutaO + "\"  \\\\" + "" + rutaD + "");
```

I'd appreciate your help.

---

Well this is what my code looks like:

```
String rutaC = "pcvw234103R\\Retrabajos_KS1_2014";

String rutaO = "D:\\Retrabajos_KS1_2014\\generales\\" + nombreC + ".pdf";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c copy \"" + rutaO + "\" \\\\" + "" + rutaC + "");
```

And at the end this is what I pass to the cmd:

```
cmd /c copy "D:\Retrabajos_KS1_2014\generales\Turbina ruidosa(material suelto),NUEVO FORMATO.pdf" \\pcvw234103R\Retrabajos_KS1_2014
```

That's how I copy files from my computer to another one, but I need to do the opposite) 
:(

Comment: `pc1234/folder/` isn't a valid path. Neither is `\\D:/reportes`.

Comment: if you can transfer files using cmd prompt, then post exact command here

Comment: Run your code, but println the final value that you would pass to `exec`.  Then copy/paste that value into a command prompt window and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic problem is that you need to break up the comnand and its arguments into *separate* Strings, like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd", "/c", "copy", "\"" + rutaO + "\"", "\\\\" + rutaD);
```

The first argument passed `exec()` is the executable command, and the following arguments are the arguments to that command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 7+, you can use the [Files.copy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) method:

```
Path source = new File("\\\\pcvw234103R\\Retrabajos_KS1_2014").toPath();
Path target = new File("D:\\Retrabajos_KS1_2014\\generales\\" + nombreC + ".pdf").toPath();
Files.copy(source, target);
```